# Stripping date from string, casting to date and checking if equal to today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a character field representing a date in the following format:

```
'yyyyMMdd-000000'
```

I'm not completely sure what the 0's represent, but I'm trying to strip those off then check if the date is the same as today's date:

```
SELECT 
      acctnum,
      acctname
FROM 
     [Server].[dbo].[Table1]
Where 
    CAST(LEFT(myDate,8) AS DATE) = CAST(GetDate() as Date)
```

When executing that statement I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like some of your values aren't valid dates. this is why storing them as a `varchar` is a bad idea.

Comment: Clean up the table. Alter column data type to date.

Comment: @Larnu That would make sense. The table is populated from an import. What is normally done in that situation?

Comment: My take: (1) Data is being loaded into a column of the appropriate datatype--here, sounds like `DATE`. (2) The process preparing the data to be loaded performs data cleansing routines, to make sure all the data being loaded is properly formatted (i.e. actually is a date). (3) The process actually loading the data has good error handling, to deal with any invalid data that is encountered. The real goal here is to have clean and valid data in the database--once properly loaded, you don't have to worry about form and format, as you'll know it's good. Get it right at load time, not afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_cast()` instead:

```
Where TRY_CAST(LEFT(myDate, 8) AS DATE) = CAST(GetDate() as Date)
```

Then, you can find the bad data using:

```
select myDate
from [Server].[dbo].[Table1]
Where TRY_CAST(LEFT(myDate, 8) AS DATE) is null;
```

You can attempt to find the bad data with something like:

```
select myDate
from [Server].[dbo].[Table1]
where mydate not like '[12][90][0-9][01][0-9][0-9][1-3][0-9]%'
```

This doesn't find all bad examples, but if something is glaring it will pop.

Comment: Unfortunately the database is a SQL Server 2008 database. I'm guessing that's why I'm getting a message about try_cast not being a built-in function name. Adding And myDate <> null made the query run though.

Comment: Another good reason to get off a *completely* unsupported version of SQL Server then, @Rich .

Comment: @Larnu True, but out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table1 table
(
    acctnum int,
    acctname varchar(10),
    myDate varchar(20)
)

insert into @table1(acctnum, acctname, myDate)
values(1, 'A', '20200401-000000'),
(2, 'B',  convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 112) + '-000000'),
(3, 'C',  convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 112) + '-000000'),
(4, 'D',  'abcd-0000');

select *
from @table1;

select *, case isdate(stuffdate) when 1 then cast(stuffdate as date) end
from
(
select *, stuff(stuff(stuff(myDate, 14, 0, ':'), 12, 0, ':'), 9, 1, ' ') as stuffdate
from @table1
where myDate like convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 112)+'%'
) as t;

select *
from
(
select *, stuff(stuff(stuff(myDate, 14, 0, ':'), 12, 0, ':'), 9, 1, ' ') as stuffdate
from @table1
) as t
where case isdate(stuffdate) when 1 then cast(stuffdate as date) end = convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 112);
```